# Can't create some records in published web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have published an ASP.NET.Core web application to a hosting site. There appears a strange problem I cannot solve. In development, I can create a record but after publishing, I cannot do it and when I look at browser console I don't see any errors. The strange thing is after publishing I can create records for all other 6 entity types, but there is a problem only with 1 entity type so it shouldn' be a general problem. This entity has relations to other entities.

Aftrer submitting the form, the action to return doesn't work 
(return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Orders", new { id = order.Id });
)

instead [HttpGet] Create page is reloaded

Controller action

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(OrderViewModel orderViewModel)
{
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
var order = _mapper.Map<Order>(orderViewModel);
_context.Orders.Add(order);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Orders", new { id = order.Id });
}
return View(orderViewModel);
}
```

Razor view

```
<form action="/Orders/Create" method="post" id="orderCreateForm">    
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()    
</form>
```

Comment: I have removed 'ModelState.IsValid'  check, tried again and that solved the problem. So the problem occurs while checking the validity of the model, it is still strange to me why that works in my local comupter, but not in the hosting environment. If someone can enlighten me how to debug Controller action in hosting environment and what modelstate returns in controller, would be glad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add validation summary in razor view code as below and see what errors you get.

```
<form action="/Orders/Create" method="post" id="orderCreateForm">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })    
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()    
</form>
```